# I want to use the multiple currencies option for amount in my iphone app is any api or database file of currencies available?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, database, currency

I am currently working on iphone app and need your help.  In my app I am giving the user the option to save his or her expenses according to his or her country's currency mood,   because the user can belong to any country like USA,  Australia etc.

It is really hard for me to sit and enter the currency option one by one.  So is  any API or database file available for this purpose?

NOTE : I need 4 types data belong to one currency.

1. Currency Name
2. Currency Symbol
3. Currency Code
4. Country Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official ISO list of countries and their currencies is maintained by the SIX Clearing bank.  They provide [downloadable XLS and XML files](http://www.currency-iso.org/iso_index/iso_tables/iso_tables_a1.htm).

Those files do not include the currency symbols.  Fortunately XE has a list of countries' currencies, including codes and symbols.  [Find it here](http://www.xe.com/symbols.php).  The symbols are presented using a special font rather than as images; however it would be a simple, if rather tedious, matter to turn that page into a set of PNG files.